# Using React circular progressbar in nextjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I installed react circular `progressbar` and imported it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import "../css/myCourses.css"
import { CircularProgressbar } from 'react-circular-progressbar';
import 'react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css';

const MyCourses = () => {
    const percentage = 66;
    return (
        <>
            <div className='mt-3'>
                        <CircularProgressbar value={percentage} text={`${percentage}%`} />
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default MyCourses;
```

But I get this error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
```

This is where i call the MyCourses component:

```
import React from 'react';
import "../css/overview.css"
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import search from "../../public/images/search.svg"
import MyCourses from '../components/myCourses';
import Planning from '../components/planning';

const Overview = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <div className='overview_container'>
                <p>Hello <b>BRUNO</b>, welcome back!</p>
                <div className='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline'>
                    <div className='heading d-flex align-items-baseline justify-content-between'>
                        <p className='me-4'>My Courses</p>
                        <Link href={'/overview'}>View All</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className='d-flex'>
                        <Image 
                        src={search}
                        alt="search"
                        />
                        <input className='ms-3' type="text" placeholder='Search...' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <MyCourses/>
                <Planning/>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Overview;
```

Comment: Can you provide the versions of react and react-circular-progressbar that you are using

Comment: Sure : "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0"

Comment: I tried switching to react version 16, but still got the same error.

Comment: I guess the problem is related to your importing of mycourses.css, I got this error : "Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>" which is what you would expect, it worked perfectly when I removed that line, instead of importing a global css file use css modules

Comment: thanks for answering, I tried , but it didn't make any difference for my case.

Comment: Can you add the code of the page in which you are using `MyCourses` component

Comment: Okay, I added the other component.

Comment: I have replicated your project and still got the same errors concerning the global css files, worked fine when I moved the css imports to the custom `<App>` component.

Comment: I used `react-circle-progress-bar` instead of `react-circular-progressbar` and it worked fine. Also it is simpler

Comment: That's good to know, but what about those global imports did they work fine?

Comment: Yes, they didn't cause any errors. I don't know how but it works fine